# Changing pagination from 20 to 10 records per page

Tags: php, pagination, page-numbering

I am using the script below, from here >> http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html

to try and show 10 records per page, but im having problems changing it for some reason and cant understand why, all I have done is changed the 20's to 10's, but for some reason its showing 5 records per page (there are currently 11 records in the database).

```
    <?php 
    // check the user is part of the admin group
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$connection)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("rcsetch", $connection);

    if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 10; 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM u5b0y_chronoforms_data_submitusedequipment ORDER BY cf_id ASC LIMIT $start_from, 10"; 
    $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql,$connection); 
    ?> 
    <table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Phone</td></tr>
    <?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
    ?> 
                <tr>
                <td><? echo $row["manufacturer"]; ?></td>
                <td><? echo $row["model"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
    <?php 
    }; 
    ?> 
    </table>
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(cf_id) FROM u5b0y_chronoforms_data_submitusedequipment"; 
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result); 
    $total_records = $row[0]; 
    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / 10); 

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
                echo "<a href='test.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
    }; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Did it work prior to when you changed it?

Comment: Im not sure as I only have 11 records, but it appeared to as they were all displayed

Comment: Ah, that means the query is working fine then :/ Which means it probably isn't to do with the structure of the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
function paging($url,$sql,$offset,$page){
    $link="";
    $total=countrows($sql);

    $totalpages=ceil($total/$offset);

    $prev=$page-1;
    $next=$page+1;

    if($url=="dashboard.php"){
        $link="dashboard.php?";
    }else{
        $link=$url."&";
    }

    echo '<div id="paging">';
        if($total>$offset){
            echo "<span class='note'>Total ".$total."</span> | <span class='note'> Results of Page ".$page."</span><br/>";
            echo ($page>1)?'<a href="'.$link.'pg='.$prev.'">Prev</a>' : '<span class="s">Prev</span>';
            for($i=1;$i<=$totalpages;$i++){
                echo ($page!=$i)?'<a href="'.$link.'pg='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>' : '<span class="s">'.$i.'</span>';
            }
            echo ($page<$totalpages)? '<a href="'.$link.'pg='.$next.'">Next</a>' : '<span class="s">Next</span>';
        }else{
            echo "<span class='note'>Total ".$total."</span>";
        }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

check this function, hope it could help you. just edit the variable url value